# Identical BST's

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

Two trees are said to be identical if they contain same set of elements but may have different structures.
e.g. 4,3,5 and 5,4,3

How to check whether the two trees are identical?

One approach i can think of is to use hashing. For each element in the first tree, the corresponding count is incremented. For each element in the second tree, the count is decremented. At the end, the the hash is empty, we are sure that trees are identical.
Time complexity: O(N)
Space complexity: O(N)

But, this approach doesn't make use of whether tree is a BST or a simple BINARY TREE.

Approach 2: Take inorder traversal of both the trees in array. We are with two arrays having sorted data. Do a linear search to check whether arrays are identical are not.
Time complexity: O(N)
Space complexity: O(N)

But, I wanted to know that does there exist any better solution?

Comment: What do you mean by “two trees are identical”?  Does it mean (1) they contain the same set of elements, (2) the shapes of the trees are the same but they possibly contain different elements, (3) both the elements and the shapes are the same, or (4) something else?  It seems to me that people are implicitly assuming different interpretations and giving answers to different questions.

Comment: “two trees are identical” means they contain same set of elements.

Comment: Please edit the question.  As you can see from all these different interpretations, saying “trees are identical” is ambiguous.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: "Ambiguous" is an overstatement; it is quite clear what "identical" means (if not to the OP).

Comment: @Raphael: In case you have not noticed, OP has already edited the question after my comment, and now the question defines what it means for BSTs to be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latter solution seems better than your former, as while the worst-case time for the latter is O(N), the best case (where the first elements in the in-order traversals differ) would be Ω(1), while for the former, best-case time would still be Ω(N) as you have to wait until the end to know for sure.

As an optimization for the latter one, though, couldn't you just use a pointer to the current element in each tree rather than making copies of all the data? The algorithm for in-order traversal of a tree (with natural ordering, at least) doesn't require making any copies of the data. That way your space complexity would be O(1).

Comment: Even if we avoid the explicit space complexity, we will have to go with the recursive inorder traversal. But this will also consume space for recursive stack.

Comment: I don't believe a stack is necessary if you utilize an iterative algorithm for binary tree traversal, as long as your child nodes have pointers to their parents (which, admittedly, would increase the size of the tree from one without back-pointers by about the same size as an array of pointers to the nodes. Though a self-balancing BST might need such pointers anyway). You could simply go all the way down the lowest-value path first, then just keep going to the parent and going down the next path. If the parent has no second path, just go up to its parent and try again until you reach the root.

Comment: Surprisingly many data structures based on balanced binary search trees do not require pointers to parents for balancing.  Implementations without back pointers are often preferred in functional programming because back pointers do not play nicely with immutable data structures.

Comment: How often would you utilize an immutable balanced binary search tree? Or is it just that functional programming utilizes/tends to utilize immutable data structures over mutable ones? Either way, a good point.

Comment: Immutable data structures including immutable balanced binary trees are basic building blocks when programming in at least Haskell and ML.  (By immutable, I mean that update operations do not modify the data structure in place and instead create a new data structure which shares most of the elements with the old data structure.  It might be more precise to call it “persistent.”)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen a lot of immutable objects that work that way in order to be completely interchangeable with mutable versions (in Java, at least; Java's concept of interfaces pretty much requires that for most mutable/immutable class pairs in its standard library, as the mutable versions are generally subclasses of the immutable ones, iirc).

Answer (score 6):

*This answers the question as originally phrased, that is after **identity** of trees in the sense of same structure and elements.*

Comparing in-order (or any other) sequentialisation won't work: different trees have the same traversal. For example, the trees

[image]
<sup>[[source](https://github.com/akerbos/sesketches/blob/gh-pages/src/so_10951927.tikz)]</sup>

have the same in-order traversal `a,b,c,d,e`. You can use [*two* (different) traversals](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/439/98) and check whether they are the same, respectively.

The classic solution, however, is a recursive algorithm:

```
  equal Leaf(x)       Leaf(y)       => x == y
| equal Node(x,l1,r1) Node(y,l2,r2) => x == y && equal(l1,l2) && equal(r1,r2)
| equal _             _             => false;
```

It performs tree traversals on both trees simultaneously and takes time Θ(n), n the maximum of the respective number of nodes.

---

Regarding the updated question, checking the in-order traversals for element-wise equality is enough. Note that by definition, the in-order traversal of a BST is the sorted list of the stored elements, therefore this approach is correct. In recursive form, this is the algorithm:

```
  inorder Leaf(x)     = [x]
| inorder Node(x,l,r) = (inorder l) ++ [x] ++ (inorder r);

  equal []     []     = true
| equal x1::r1 x2::r2 = x1 == x2 && (equal r1 r2)
| equal _      _      = false;

  sameElems t1 t2 = let 
                      e1 = inorder t1
                      e2 = inorder t2
                    in
                      equal e1 e2
                    end;
```

If list concatenations can be done in time O(1), this runs in time Θ(n) and space Θ(n); iterative solutions are certainly as good, and have probably better constants.

If you wanted to do this check in o(n) time, you could not even look at every element. In general, both trees contain pairwise different elements so you can not exploit any ranges, therefore I every general element-equality check takes time Ω(n) (assume a faster algorithm and construct two trees it fails for).

Space can be done better than O(n), though. If you implement in-order [cleverly](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/6358)¹, you only ever need O(1) additional space (pointer to current elements, some managing counters/flags).

---

1. Note that this algorithm destroys the tree temporarily, so it is not suitable in concurrent settings.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with hashing is if you have two binary search trees, `{2, 1, 3}` and `{0, 0, 6}`, they can have the same total hash code and you still have different elements.

The in order traversal method is probably the most efficient one, and it is my suspicion that `O(n)` is the best you can ever get considering there are `n` equality comparisons that you need to make.

Comment: What if we implement our own hashing(Suppose we are going to implement it in C & not JAVA)?

Comment: Unless if you can guarantee `item1.HashCode() + item2.HashCode() != item3.HashCode() + item4.HashCode()` for all combinations of `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, `item4` unless `item1` and `item2` are not `item3` and `item4`, adding hashes together is never a sufficient condition to check for equality.

Comment: Another way to look at this is `HashCode()` returns an `int`, which has 2^32 - 1 possible values. Your binary tree can contain potentially infinite values, each of type `int`, with `2^32n - 1` possible combinations (where `n` is the number of elements in your bst).

You can't possibly match each of those to a unique hash code.